# Problems while using Flutter Provider package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, provider

I am creating a very simple app to practice flutter provider package. The app has a bulb which on click , should change it's background and the screen's background , using provider. But this doesnt seem to work. TBH this is a lot confusing

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MainApp());

class Data extends ChangeNotifier{
  bool isOn = false;
  void toggle(){
    this.isOn = !this.isOn;
    notifyListeners();
    print("new value is $isOn");
  }
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
      create: (context) => Data(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Provider.of<Data>(context).isOn ? Colors.yellow[100] : Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stick(),
            Bulb(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Stick extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      width: 40,
      color: Colors.brown,
    );
  }
}

class Bulb extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BulbState createState() => _BulbState();
}

class _BulbState extends State<Bulb> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 250,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(100),
              topRight: Radius.circular(100),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
          color: Provider.of<Data>(context).isOn ? Colors.yellow : Colors.white,
      ),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          Provider.of<Data>(context).toggle();
          setState(() {
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The tree structure has a main app which houses a Home app , which houses 2 other widgets , a stick and a bulb inside a container. I am trying to update the background of bulb and the Home widget when the bulb is clicked. Bulb has a gesture detector
Any kind of hint or help appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `listen: false` to the provider call :

```
Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).toggle();
```

Comment: It worked ! Please explain how did that work ! Also do point out if there is anything wrong with the way I am using provider

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but this is the doc on it : _If [listen] is true, later value changes will trigger a new [State.build] to widgets, and [State.didChangeDependencies] for [StatefulWidget]._

Comment: For anyone still looking for other ways to use provider, try Consumer<T> widget. it is better than calling Provider.of( ) each time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `Provider` constructor has a named parameter `listen` which is equal to `true` by default. And this behavour force rebuilding while you use `Provider.of()` method. It is imposible to call `build` while current buiding is still active. That is why you suggested to set `listen` to `false` because it disables default behavour.

It is better to implement like this:

```dart
...

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Data>(
      builder: (_, data, __) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          backgroundColor: data.isOn ? Colors.yellow[100] : Colors.black,
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Stick(),
                Bulb(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
...

class _BulbState extends State<Bulb> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<Data>(
      builder: (_, data, __) {
        return Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 250,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(100),
              topRight: Radius.circular(100),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)
            ),
            color: data.isOn ? Colors.yellow : Colors.white,
          ),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              data.toggle();
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```